# Opening sub-window when double clicking on row in main window

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Right now I get a window output with 4 columns from my dataset.

However, there are a lot more columns being processed behind the scenes.

Right now I have code where I click on a row and it prints every column to console.

```
tableview.setRowFactory(tv -> {
 TableRow row = new TableRow<>();
 row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
  if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
   Object rowData = row.getItem();
   System.out.println(rowData);
```

How can I convert this from a `print` statement to opening a new window?

I also have a `catlist`which has a list of category names for each column in the new window, if that's necessary.

Comment: A separate window for each element?

Comment: Each time I click on a row, open a separate window.

Or just open up a sub-row in the main window.

Honestly anything that just lets me expand the rest of the data when double clicking.

Comment: You can use a `Dialog` if you want a new window, and a `ListView` to display them.

Comment: What data do you want to show on this `separate window`?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha `rowData` and `catlist`.